# java hdfs api protocol buffer exception

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I'm running a java app using `hadoop-2.0.5-alpha`. My code looks like:

```
FileSystem fileSystem = FileSystem.get(conf);
Path path = new Path("/tmp/sample.txt");
System.out.println(fileSystem.exists(path));
```

But I get an exception

```
com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Message missing required fields: callId, status
```

I haven't been able to find much on what causes this error. Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you provide your environment? What's your HDFS version? It seems you are using hadoop-2.0.5-alpha in the client. But the sever version may be too slow. Type `hadoop version` to check the version.

Comment: Ah yes, you may be correct here. Let me try changing the version and I'll post back shortly.

Comment: That was it, thanks. Can you post that as an answer?

Comment: OK. Thanks! I'll post it.

Comment: I had the same issue (Hadoop server 2.10 in Docker, Spark 2.3.2+hadoop-client 2.6.5). It magically disappeared after recreating Hadoop container from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are using hadoop-2.0.5-alpha in the client. But the sever version may be too low.

Type `hadoop version` to check the version.